# Grid to list view, CSS only (w/ Flexbox)

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

While there is a simple solution for this with javascript, I'm hoping to find a CSS-only solution (using CSS3, flexbox layout most likely).

when i click on list view button, my card change. I want to have the following layout: [image: (cf screenshot)]

The first card is easy to make. But while keeping the same structure, I cannot place my elements as on the screenshot. I wanted to reorder my items with the "Order" property (l-55 to l-67 in codepen), but it obviously does not work.

Second problem, how to place items on the same line, and after the second, make a line break?

Do you think it's stupid to persist in using CSS to do this?

Thank you.

My complete code is available in Codepen:

#### http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZNKxr

HTML:

```
a.card.card--large
    .card__container
      .card__body
        .card__category Category
        .card__title My title
        .card__date April 2016
        .card__text
        |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

CSS:

```
.card--large {
  height: 130px;

  .card__body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .card__category {
      order: 3;
    }

    .card__title {
      order: 1;
    }

    .card__date {
      order: 2;
    }

    .card__text {
      order: 4;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no click property in css. You may want to use the radio box hack to achieve the same

Comment: I was planning to use javascript for that. It's just that I do not want to rearrange my component via JS.

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing indentation in the html code (`.card__text`) and this is the reason, order doesn't work.

To order elements and make a line break after the second element try this:

```
.card--large {
  .card__body::before, .card__body::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }

  .card__body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    .card__category {
      order: 1;
    }

    .card__text {
      order: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqNbQZ)